# Javascript document ready is not running

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is my html page:

```
<html>
       <div class="panel-body text-center">
          <div class="ttl-info">
            STOK TM
          </div>
          <h4 class="show-value">
              <span id="stktimur">0</span>
          <h4>
       </div>
    

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#stktimur').ambilData({
              url : '<?php echo site_url('data/datastk') ?>',
              reload: 65,
              success: function(dt, th){
                  $('#stktimur').data('list', dt.data);
                  if( parseInt($('#stktimur').text()) != parseInt(dt.total) ){
                      $('#stktimur').text(parseInt(dt.total) )
                        .textEffect({effect: 'jumble',jumbleColor :'#FFF', letterJumble: txt});
                  }
              }
          })
       }
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) preferably in a [Stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: What are you expecting to see versus the actual results? Is this saved as a html file rather than a php file?

Comment: Please provide details of the debugging you've done. There's ***a lot*** of reasons an AJAX request may fail - such as missing a `)` as in your code above

Comment: I want to when onclick at #stktimur, can running:

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `<script>` tag. Also some formatting issues.

Try it like this:

```html
<div class="panel-body text-center">
   <div class="ttl-info">
     STOK TM
   </div>
   <h4 class="show-value">
       <span id="stktimur">0</span>
   <h4>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#stktimur').ambilData({
            url : '<?php echo site_url("data/datastk") ?>',
            reload: 65,
            success: function(dt, th){
                $('#stktimur').data('list', dt.data);
                if( parseInt($('#stktimur').text()) != parseInt(dt.total) ){
                    $('#stktimur').text( parseInt(dt.total) ).textEffect({effect: 'jumble',jumbleColor :'#FFF', letterJumble: txt});
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: yes, but, when on click at #stktimur, cannot display result on data list

Comment: There were also some formatting issues in your script. I've fixed these and updatet my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do ajax request while the **stktimur** is click. The correct code should be like this.

[jQuery Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

[jQuery Click Event Listener](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-handler)

```
<div class="panel-body text-center">
    <div class="ttl-info">
        STOK TM
    </div>
    <h4 class="show-value">
        <span id="stktimur">0</span>
    </h4>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#stktimur').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('data/datastk') ?>",
                success: function (dt, th) {
                    $('#stktimur').data('list', dt.data);
                    if (parseInt($('#stktimur').text()) != parseInt(dt.total)) {
                        $('#stktimur').text(parseInt(dt.total)).textEffect({
                            effect: 'jumble',
                            jumbleColor: '#FFF',
                            letterJumble: txt
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```